# Tabbar controller accessing active navigation controller of current tab through app delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, tabbarcontroller

I have the following setup. I have a TabBarController with three NavigationControllers in it. What I want to do is the following:

I have a mapview with annotations on it and a button on the annotation, I implemented the delegate method that fires when the annotation button is tapped. My problem is that the delegate for my mapview is also a subview of the mapview

```
[self.mapView addSubview:self];
[self.mapView setRegion:region];
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
```

This is in a custom class that I use to draw routes on my mapview.

In other words the following method is in the custom class which is the delegate of my mapview

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    Helper *myHelper = [Helper sharedManager];
    StationInfo *myViewController = [[StationInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"StationInfo" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     myViewController.station = [myHelper.stations objectAtIndex:[myHelper.stations indexOfObject:[view annotation]]];
    GautrainiPhoneAppDelegate *del = (GautrainiPhoneAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    //missing code to push the controller onto the navigation controller that is on the active tab in the tabBarcontroller

}
```

So how can I push a view controller onto the navigation stack of the active tab using the app delegate that contains my tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a viable solution for what I wanted to do. I created an outlet for the navigationcontroller I was trying to access and then just pushed my view